# Unable to get code coverage using sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I am using jacoco plugin to get code coverage using jenkins. I am able to see code coverage. When I am trying to use the same jacoco.exec file to generate sonar code coverage it shows : No JaCoCo analysis of project coverage can be done since there is no class files. I am using below sonar properties :

```
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.junit.reportsPath=TEST.XML
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=jacoco.exec
```

I am using SonarQube 5.3 & Jacoco plugin 2.0.1 & jacoco maven plugin 0.7.5

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the JaCoCo Maven plugin implies that you're working with a Maven project. Yet you list SonarQube Scanner-format properties, implying to me that you're running your analysis with SonarQube Scanner rather than with SonarQube Scanner for Maven. Try the latter and you should find that this "just works".